# How to ellipsise in the selected value in a combobox?

Tags: silverlight, combobox, truncate

In our Silverlight page, I got comboboxes with different values. When selected, some values are too long to fit in the collapsed combobox.

[image]

I would like it to ellipsise ("System Use..." with three dots in the end).

In the dropdown the full name of the value can be seen, but when collapsed I would like the selected value to ellipsise. It feels like an obvious thing, as a drop down generally affords more space than the collapsed control, but still I cannot find an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37503/Auto-Ellipsis.
It's similar to Zenexar's suggestion, uses a more efficient reduction algorithm in the general case. But it also writes about other types of 'ellipsing', which might also suit your needs perhaps.

Comment: That's a well thought-out approach, taking into account both iteration complexity and measuring text, so I am marking this as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take the selected UIElement.  Compare the RenderedWidth and RenderedHeight to the DesiredSize, the latter of which will be adjusted based on how the element is cut off.  Repeatedly remove characters, append ellipsis, and invalidate the layout until the DesiredSize is smaller than or equal to the RenderedWidth/RenderedHeight

Comment: +1 for informative, thanks, but I hope for something more obvious and less modifications.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with silverlight and I don't really know if you were suggesting on manipulating the datasource (strings?) directly, but if so than this seems like a bit of a hassle when you are working with a dynamically resizing control. Especially when making it smaller and then larger: the dropped characters are gone?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to check the length of the selected item.  If the length is more than a predetermined character length, cut off the rest and append three periods.

Comment: Do you really suggest counting character pixel lengths?

Comment: I don't think he's suggesting counting pixel lengths.  I think he's suggesting getting an approximation based on character length.